# How would I achieve a download button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, download

On my website index, I'm currently displaying 18 random images, here's the code I currently use to display these images:

Here's my website I want to implement this feature on:
http://www.freevatars.co.uk

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write(getImageTag());
</script>
```

JS:

```
var imageURLs = [
"css/images/avatars/1.png"
 , "css/images/avatars/2.jpg"
 , "css/images/avatars/3.png"
 , "css/images/avatars/4.png"
 , "css/images/avatars/5.png"
 , "css/images/avatars/6.png"
 , "css/images/avatars/7.png" 
 , "css/images/avatars/8.jpg"
 , "css/images/avatars/9.jpg"
 , "css/images/avatars/10.png"
 , "css/images/avatars/11.jpg"
 , "css/images/avatars/12.jpg"
 , "css/images/avatars/13.jpg"
 , "css/images/avatars/14.png"
 , "css/images/avatars/15.jpg"
 , "css/images/avatars/16.png"
 , "css/images/avatars/17.jpg"
 , "css/images/avatars/18.jpg"
 ];
 function getImageTag() {
var img = '<img src=\"';
var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * imageURLs.length);
img += imageURLs[randomIndex];
img += '\" alt=\"Oh no, the image is broken!\"/>';
return img;
}
// Images in JS code go up to 410, so I have only placed 18 here to shorten it.
```

I was hoping to achieve a download button or a like system on the hover, however, with the image being displayed randomly with JS, I'm not able to use the standard HTML ahref download code because I would need an absolute path to the image.

Does anybody know how I could achieve this and keep the random images?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this what you're going for? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eWaJBw

Comment: It worked! It's messed up the spacing and such with the images, but it's nothing I hope I can't fix, thanks alot Michael!